# ¿Qué pasa si volvemos a ejecutar un código de PHP que no termina de ejecutarse?

Tags: php, pdo

Supongamos un codigo de PDO Mysql que está ejecutándose y mientras no termina de hacerlo, recargamos la página y lo volvemos a ejecutar. ¿Qué pasa con mi código? Continúa ejecutándose y luego vuelve a ejecutarse otra vez, o termina en el punto al que ha llegado? ¿Si habían varios insert es posible que insertase valores erroneos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uno de los problemas frecuentes al desarrollar con PHP, era exactamente el escenario que planteaste al final:

Si recargas la página cuando está en ejecución un archivo PHP que está realizando una inserción de valores en la base de datos; estos terminan de insertarse, e inmediatamente se vuelve a ejecutar el mismo código PHP, provocando inserciones duplicadas.

### Este comportamiento puede ser controlado usando:

- Protección contra *Cross-Site Request Forgery*. A pesar que este no es su propósito de existir, pero es un efecto secundario que tiene al usarlo. Se trata de:

Generar un token (un hash) desde PHP, guardarlo en sesión y enviarlo al cliente. Podría ser por ejemplo, dentro del archivo php que voy a servir al cliente:

```
session_start();                                  //Arrancar sesión
$_SESSION['csrf'] = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)); //Guardo hash generado
...
...  //Más adelante, podría agregarlo por ejemplo en un form
...  //que contenga dentro del mismo un input hidden con el csrf
<input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['csrf']; ?>">
...
```

Cuando el cliente realice una llamada al servidor, tiene que enviar el token. En el servidor se controla que sea el mismo, se lo destruye y se ejecuta el procedimiento normal. Entonces, dentro del nuevo archivo encargado de recibir la petición Post:

```
if ($_POST["csrf"] == $_SESSION["csrf"]) {
  session_destroy();
  ...                   //Lógica procedimiento normal.
}
```

Ya con este control, si se recarga antes de terminar, al momento que el servidor quiera ejecutar por segunda vez ya no cuenta con el token dentro de sesión al haber sido destruida, por lo cual, no realiza ningún procedimiento.

- Agregar una redirección al finalizar la ejecución del código.

Usando el método header

```
if (alguna_condicion) {
   //Lógica procedimiento normal.
}
header('Location: otra_pagina.php');  //Debería estar al final de todo.
```

---

Revisando un poco la documentación de PHP; [Manejo de Conexiones](http://php.net/manual/es/features.connection-handling.php), plantea 4 escenarios posibles. En el cual nunca plantea que la ejecución del script pueda ser abortada por interrupción.

Únicamente son abortadas cuando se vence el tiempo límite de espera (30 segundos por defecto) o cuando un cliente se desconecta (Salvo que se configure para evitarlo, o se use *ignore_user_abort()*).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Francute, podrias poner el ejemplo de un codigo con proteccion ante Cross-Site Request Forgery y el codigo que usas para rediccionar? Yo tengo el mismo problema y lo que pasa es que utilizo la redireccion con `header(Location: ... );` pero el mismo tiene que estar al principio de la pagina aunque sí que debería dejar al código de "seguir hasta ser completamente ejecutado"...

Comment: Ahí edité la respuesta. Perdón por el formato, aún no le agarro la mano a las vueltas que tiene...